Can I create a C# gRPC service using runtime loaded proto definitions?
I am creating a C# application that I want to host a large number of gRPC services (hundreds or more) and the business logic for how to process those gRPC requests is basically the same for all of them. This application is essentially translating a received gRPC request into a different protocol and passing that translated request on to a different service.
I've been able to create a service like this in Go using packages like the following:
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protodesc"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoregistry"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/dynamicpb"
    "github.com/bufbuild/protocompile/parser"
    "github.com/bufbuild/protocompile/reporter"

Essentially what my Go version of this service does is read proto files from a directory and uses bufbuild as a runtime version of protoc to get the service descriptors, etc. for those proto files. I then register types and services from those proto files but when I hook up a handler for each service, I point it to a common/shared handler that is the same for every service. I based my solution off this example: gRPC GO Single Generic Service Handler
Unfortunately, I cannot use Go for the application I'm working on now (I am limited to C# due to some other dependencies with the project) but I need to essentially do the same thing: Load a set of proto files and register a common/shared gRPC service handler for every service defined in those proto files.
I'm sure if I copied enough of the dotnet grpc code, I could figure out how to register my own generic handler but I am looking for a less intensive way of doing that.
Another requirement is that I want to use gRPC reflection to provide service discoverability for all of these dynamically loaded gRPC services.
How would one go about doing this using C# .net gRPC without having to write my own gRPC support from the ground up?
